# Providing a value to get an "EMPTY" or "BLANK" cell

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas, google-sheets-formula

In my Google sheet, I have a column 'A' of values that I have not fully filled in. In the next column 'B' I am calculating the fractional change in 'A' relative to the value in A1.

For any given row I use, e.g. `=(B2-$A$2)/$A$2)`.

When a value in 'A' has not yet been added, the calculated value in 'B' is shown as '-1'.

[image]

Instead of '-1' I would like the cells to remain empty.
I tried the following IF statement in cells B2:B8 that checks if the 'A' cell is empty. If so, I want to provide a "value_if_true" that will give a blank or empty cell, however, I am unable to work out how to do this. "BLANK" does not work.

`=IF(ISBLANK(A2), BLANK, (A2-$A$1)/$A$1)`

[image]

Is there something I can replace "BLANK" within my statement, that will show B4 and B6 as empty cells?

For bonus points; if the cells in column B were to be formatted as percentages (likely that I will do this), there could be a problem if the values are not numerical (or not empty) e.g. if you try to format an empty string ' ' as a percentage it will probably give an error. So the solution to the question should be a genuine, empty cell, not an empty string!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

also can be simply just:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A2), , 100*(A2-$A$1)/$A$1)
```

and this can be done in array formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(A1:A), , 100*(A1:A-A1)/A1))
```

Comment: Yes, thanks. I am sure that I tried this before and it did not work. Now it works. Perhaps I had some other error that was causing a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to be " ", and I was wrong about it causing an error in percentage-formatted cells.

[image]